# Any ball is connected?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness, connectedness

Let $X$ be a compact , metric space. 
Assume that the closure of every each open ball it the closed ball with same center and radius.

Prove that any ball in this space is connected.

Answer (score 4):

I will use $B(x,r)$ for the open ball centered at $x$ with radius $r$, $\bar B(x,r)$ for the corresponding closed ball and $\overline{B(x,r)}$ for the closure of the open ball in $X$.

First, notice that it is sufficient to prove that every closed ball is connected, because of $$B(x,r) = \bigcup_{s<r}\bar B(x,s).$$ (Remember that a union of a family of connected sets with non-empty intersection is connected.)

Suppose some closed ball $\bar B(x,r)$ is disconnected. Then $\bar B(x,r)=U+V$ for some clopen subsets $U,V$ of $\bar B(x,r)$. But $\bar B(x,r)$ is closed in $X$, so $U$ and $V$ are also closed in $X$. Since $X$ is compact, this implies that $U$ and $V$ are compact. Assume without loss of generality, that $x\in U$. Since $V$ is compact, $\min_{y\in V} d(x,y)=:q$ exists. Note that $0<q\leq r$. Fix a point $y\in V$ such that $d(x,y)=q$.

Observe that $B(x,q)\cap V=\emptyset$. Therefore, $B(x,q)\subseteq U$. But $U$ is closed in $X$, so $\overline{B(x,q)}\subseteq U$. On the other hand, $\bar B(x,q)$ contains $y$, so $\bar B(x,q)\nsubseteq U$. So, $\bar B(x,q)\neq\overline{B(x,q)}$.

We conclude that if $\bar B(x,r)=\overline{B(x,r)}$ holds for all $x\in X, r\in[0,\infty)$, all balls must be connected.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $X$ is not connected. Then there exists a set $F\subset X$, such that $F, K=X\smallsetminus F$ are non-empty, open and closed, and as they are closed they are compact.

This means that 
$$
r=\mathrm{dist}(F,K)>0,
$$
and further there exist $x\in F$ and $y\in K$, such that $d(x,y)=r$.

In particular, $$\big(F\cup B(x,r)\big)\cap K=\varnothing,$$
and thus
$$
F\subset F\cup B(x,r)\subset X\smallsetminus K=F,
$$
which implies that $F= F\cup B(x,r)$ and
$$
F=\overline F= \overline{F\cup B(x,r)}=\overline F\cup \overline B(x,r),
$$
which is a contradiction since $y\not\in F$, but $y\in \overline B(x,r)$.